# CodeWars - Growth of a Population

Tags: python

> In a small town the population is p0 = 1000 at the beginning of a year. The population regularly increases by 2 percent per year and moreover 50 new inhabitants per year come to live in the town. How many years does the town need to see its population greater or equal to p = 1200 inhabitants?

I have just tried to attempt some challenges from Codewars. and unfortunately 1 test out of 207 is failing and I'm not able to find the error since I am new to Python.

```
def nb_year(p0, percent, aug, p):
    i=0
    while p0<p:
       p0 = p0+(p0*(percent/100))+aug
        i+=1
    return i
```

error - 3 should be 4

Comment: Does [that](https://github.com/LennyBoyatzis/Codewars-Challenges/blob/master/growth-of-a-population.py) solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
def nb_year (p0, pmax, percent, extra):
    '''
    p0 (int): Initial population
    pmax (int): Expected maximum population
    percent (float): % increase in population per year
    extra (int): Number of extra people settling in the city every year.
    '''
    p = p0 
    years = 0
    while (p<=pmax): # Loop break when population exceeds pmax
        p += ((percent/100)*p0)+extra # Add the increase in population to the population of the previous year and number of extra people
        years += 1
    return years

## Given:
# Initial population = 1000 (p0 = 1000)
# Expected maximum population = 1200 (pmax = 1200)
# % increase per year = 2 (percent = 2.0)
# No. of extra people coming every year = 50 (extra = 50)

print ("Required number of years:", nb_year(1000, 1200, 2, 50))
```

On running this code you will get the output:

```
Required number of years: 3
>>>
```

If you still have any queries, ask me in the comments.

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish Thank you for your suggestion. Explanation has been added to the answer.

Comment: "Should probably work." and "The code is self-explanatory." are *not* an answer.  Please either test the answer and remove the "probably work" statement, or delete the answer.  Additionally, code comments should not replace a proper textual explanation / breakdown of what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: @S3DEV Did what you said, but unfortunately I'm not able to add any text before the output due to some unknown formatting error :(    By the way, all my answers have code that are pre-tested by me and nearly bug free :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your formula `((percent/100)*p0)+extra` may give you something like 1000.9, but there is nothing like 0.9 people.

So 1000.9 people in reality is 1000, but if the p is 1000.9 and pmax 1000, the  condition `(while (p<=pmax)` will end the loop because 1000.9 is bigger than 1000.

The solution is to round the p to the nearest lower integer.

The easiest way is to use int() like this:

```
>> int(1000.9)
1000
```

Or in your code:

```
p += int(((percent/100)*p0)+extra)
```